# Google Analytics API delivers slightly different values for ga:users metric

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When querying the ga:users metric over Google Analytics API with a third-party-tool I get slightly different values (up to 3 percent, sometimes higher, sometimes lower) than in Google Analytics Audience Overview.

- I'm using the same view for both queries
- the API query contains only ga:date and ga:users
- the third-party-tool is using API v3
- sampling should not be the cause because I'm querying on a daily base (about 40'000 Users per day)
- for all other metrics the results are consistent

Does anyone have an idea of what might be the cause?